# How to update table based on count of entries of another table

Tags: sql, sas

I've table as below

```
Sample
 Source | Action |   DueDate            | Status
  A        Act_1    08DEC2017:00:00:00     Open
  A        Act_1    09DEC2017:00:00:00     closed
  A        Act_2    09DEC2017:00:00:00     Open
  A        Act_2    09DEC2017:00:00:00     closed
  A        Act_3    09DEC2017:00:00:00     Open
  B        Act_1    09DEC2017:00:00:00     Open
  B        Act_2    09DEC2017:00:00:00     closed
```

I want to  add data in my final table according to the count of entries of each Action with respect to the source.

my **final** table as

```
final
 Source | Action | Total_Received | Total_closed | OverDue
   A       Act_1      2                1              1
   A       Act_2      2                1              0
   A       Act_3      1                0              0   
   B       Act_1      1                0              0   
   B       Act_2      1                1              0
```

Total_Received is Total number of entries/rows

Total_Closed   is Total number of **closed** entries

Total_overdue  is Total number of **open** entries whose DueDate is passed

date of this time is 9DEC2017

Kindly tell me to update my table dynamically because there can be many Source types and Action Types in my system.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Mysql or sql server ?

Comment: I'm working on SAS server but sql coding will work fine

Comment: The logic for "OverDue" makes no sense to me.

Comment: if the duedate is less then the date of today

Comment: Why is your DueDate variable show datetime values instead of date values?  Can the time part be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select source, action,
       count(*) as total_received,
       sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as total_closed,
       sum(case when status = 'Open' and DueDate < Today() then 1 else 0 end) as overdue
from t
group by source, action;
```

date/time functions vary among databases.  This uses functions appropriate for SAS proc sql.

Answer (score 1):

First let's turn your data listing into a dataset so we have an example to code from.

```
data sample;
  input source $ action $ duedate :datetime. status $ ;
  format duedate datetime20.;
cards;
  A  Act_1  08DEC2017:00:00:00 Open
  A  Act_1  09DEC2017:00:00:00 closed
  A  Act_2  09DEC2017:00:00:00 Open
  A  Act_2  09DEC2017:00:00:00 closed
  A  Act_3  09DEC2017:00:00:00 Open
  B  Act_1  09DEC2017:00:00:00 Open
  B  Act_2  09DEC2017:00:00:00 closed
;
```

Counting records that meet a condition is easy in PROC SQL because SAS will evaluate boolean expressions to 1/0 values. So you can just SUM() the result to get a count of the number that are true.  If you want to compare datetime values to a date you need to convert one or the other.  I have used a date literal below but if you want today's date you could use the `DATE()` function.

```
proc sql ;
create table final as
select
  source
 ,action
 ,count(*) as Total_Received
 ,sum( status='closed' ) as Total_Closed
 ,sum( status='Open' and datepart(duedate)< '09DEC2017'd) as OverDue
from sample
group by 1,2
;
quit;
```